# How can I process deleted (or updated) rows in Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

If I wanted to `count` how many people actively work at `"Coca-Cola"`, I'd use the following query:

```scala
people.filter(_.company == "Coca-Cola").groupByKey(_.company).count().writeStream...
```

This works fine in batch mode.

However, assuming the `company` field for a `person` changes over time, or assuming people get removed from the `Dataset` entirely, how could I get this working with Structured Streaming, so the `count` remains correct?

AFAIK Structured Streaming assumes the data source is append-only: does that mean I need to track deletions and updates as separate data sources, and merge them myself?

Comment: What kind of datasource are you trying to read from?

Answer (score 1):

In general the [model of structured streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#programming-model)  is that you are reading from an ever-growing append only table.  You are correct that this means that in order to answer your question you will have to model changing a value as a deletion (possibly with a negative value in a field like `numEmployees`) followed by an insertion.

Comment: could you elaborate on that ?